# how to get specific fields by id in Netsuite using RESTlet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I could get all the standard and system fields with values of specific record by id in netsuite using below function.

```
            var response = record.load({
                type: resourceType,
                id: recordId
            });
```

But I want to get specific fields using above function like below

```
            var response = record.load({
                type: resourceType,
                id: recordId,
                fields: ["id","name"]
            });
```

I could get specific fields by search. But search will take time compare than load().

Comment: Searching by id can be faster than record load (haven't tested items but it certainly is for transactions) If it is at all slower then the difference is negligible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `search.lookupFields()` which is usually faster that a `record.load()` or `search.create()`.  It works like this:

```js
var customer = search.lookupFields({
  type: 'customer',
  id: 968,
  columns: ['internalid', 'companyname', 'daysoverdue']
});

log.debug(customer.internalid[0].value);
log.debug(customer.companyname);
log.debug(customer.daysoverdue);

log.debug(JSON.stringify(customer));
```

The response you get back from `search.lookupFields()` looks like this:

```
{
  "internalid": [{ "value": "968", "text": "968" }],
  "companyname": "DataTek Systems, Inc.",
  "daysoverdue": "0"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, But I am not able to get some fields like officephone, isprivate in Contact record type. NS throws error

Comment: That is correct. Those fields do not appear to be available when using the `search` module.  In the [NetSuite Record Browser](https://debugger.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2018_1/script/record/contact.html), the Search Columns section does not list either `officephone` or `isprivate` as an available column for search results.

Comment: Any other ways to get selected fields even those fields are not searchable?

Comment: You can get those fields by loading the record and accessing them directly.  You cannot get the via the `search` module either with `search.lookupFields()` or `search.create()`